# Comparar aquivo TXT com Tabela no banco de dados

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Possuo um arquivo TXT gerado pelo [SISOBI](http://www.dataprev.gov.br/servicos/arqsisobi.shtm), onde contém uma relação de pessoas que vieram ao óbito.

Esse txt é gerado, e necessito ler o arquivo e comparar o `CPF`, que é a única chave presente no arquivo, com o meu banco de dados e verificar se possui algum funcionário que possui o mesmo `CPF`.

Realizo o Upload do arquivo, separo as pessoas pela quantidades de caracteres (210) e retiro o `CPF` através do `SubString`.

O meu problema é como fazer para comparar o  `CPF`  com os dados retornados de minha tabela.

Meu  `Controller` que realiza essas ações está assim:

```
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            //verifica se o arquivo está nulo
            if (file == null)
            {
                TempData["MensagemError"] = "Erro ao realizar o upload do arquivo!";
                return View("Index");
            }

            //Salvar o arquivo txt
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads/" + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)));
            file.SaveAs(path);

            //Realiza a leitura do arquivo txt
            var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);

            //Separa o texto em blocos de 210 caracteres, conforme o Layout
            var partes = SplitBlocks(fileContents, 212);
            foreach (var parte in partes)
            {
                var Data = parte.Substring(155, 8);
                var Cpf = parte.Substring(163, 11);   
            }


                        //Separa os dados pelo substring e salva em suas variáveis
        var DtObito = fileContents.Substring(155, 8);
        var CPF = fileContents.Substring(163, 11);

        //converte data para o formato dd/MM/yyyy
        var dtMorte = DtObito.Substring(6, 2) + "/" + DtObito.Substring(4, 2) + "/" + DtObito.Substring(0, 4);

        //Converte o CPF para int
        var cpfcerto = Convert.ToInt64(CPF);

        //Consulta dos usuários com a variável cpf
        var usuarios = usuarioRepository.Lista.Where(u => u.NrCpf == cpfcerto).ToList();


            if (usuarios.Count > 0)
            {
                TempData["UsuarioEncontrado"] = "Existe funcionário.";
                return View(usuarios);
            }

            TempData["Usuario"] = "Nenhum funcionário encontrado.";
            return View();

        }
```

Desta forma está utilizando apenas o `Substring` para verificar se realmente está lendo o arquivo.

Pensei em colocar a consulta dentro do `For`, porém a consulta fica muita demorada, pois o arquivo `txt` possui mais de 100 mil pessoas e em média 22mb de tamanho.

Cada pessoa, com seus respectivos dados possuem o tamanho de 210 caracteres. Para realizar esta separação eu utilizo este método.

```
 public static List<String> SplitBlocks(string texto, int tamanho)
        {
            var partes = new List<String>();
            var posicao = 0;
            var total = texto.Length;
            while (total >= posicao + tamanho)
            {
                partes.Add(texto.Substring(posicao, tamanho));
                posicao += tamanho;
            }
            return partes;
        }

Tabela Funcionários para comparação.

 [Key]
        [Column("CdPessoa")]
        public double iUsuarioID { get; set; }
        public string Cod_Lotacao { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public string NmFuncionario { get; set; }
        public string nmMunicipio { get; set; }
        public string NaTipoLogradouro { get; set; }
        public string nmLogradouro { get; set; }
        public int CdCep { get; set; }
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime DtNascimento { get; set; }
  public double NrCpf { get; set; }
```

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de fazer isso. Utilizando `ViewModel` para salvar os dados do `txt` e comparar as duas. 
Salvar os dados do `txt` no Banco de dados, e após comparar os dois.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu lugar, eu faria duas [`KeyedCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) para indexar o CPF: uma para o seu *Model*, outra para a extração vinda do arquivo:

```
...
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
...

public class MortoCollection : KeyedCollection<String, Morto>
{
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(Morto item)
    {
        return item.NrCpf.ToString();
    }
}
```

Isto permite você fazer algo assim:

```
var colecao = new MortoCollection();
// Adicione aqui um item com CPF = 12345678901
var morto = colecao['12345678901'];
```

`KeyedCollection`s só permitem que você adicione itens um a um, então é interessante você implementar uma extensão pra poder adicionar vários objetos de uma vez:

```
namespace SeuProjeto.Common.Extensions
{
    public static class KeyedCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> destination,
                                   IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            foreach (T item in source)
            {
                destination.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aí você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
var colecaoMortos = new MortoCollection { usuarioRepository.Lista.ToList() };
var morto = colecao['12345678901'];
```

Já para o caso dos elementos do arquivo, acredito que a lógica já mereça ir para um *Helper* em separado, ou pelo menos uma parte dela. Eu faria um método que transforma o documento de texto em uma lista de objetos:

```
public static class LeituraArquivoHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<LinhaMortoArquivo> ConverterTxtParaLista(String arquivoBruto) 
    {
        foreach (var parte in SplitBlocks(arquivoBruto, 212))
        {
            //Separa os dados pelo substring e salva em suas variáveis
            var DtObito = parte.Substring(155, 8);
            var CPF = parte.Substring(163, 11);

            //converte data para o formato dd/MM/yyyy
            var dtMorte = DtObito.Substring(6, 2) + "/" + DtObito.Substring(4, 2) + "/" + DtObito.Substring(0, 4);

            //Converte o CPF para int
            var cpfcerto = Convert.ToInt64(CPF);

            yield return new LinhaMortoArquivo 
            {
                DataObito = dtMorte,
                Cpf = cpfcerto
            };
        }
    }
}
```

`LinhaMortoArquivo` pode ser uma classe assim:

```
public class LinhaMortoArquivo
{
    public String DataObito { get; set; }
    public String Cpf { get; set; }
}
```

Sua respectiva `KeyedCollection` poderia ser assim:

```
...
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
...

public class LinhaMortoArquivoCollection : KeyedCollection<String, LinhaMortoArquivo>
{
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(LinhaMortoArquivo item)
    {
        return item.Cpf.ToString();
    }
}
```

Portanto, pra popular uma coleção com as linhas do arquivo, você poderia fazer simplesmente assim:

```
//Realiza a leitura do arquivo txt
var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
var linhasArquivo = new LinhaMortoArquivoCollection { LeituraArquivoHelper.ConverterTxtParaLista(fileContents) };
```

Um laço de comparação seria algo como:

```
foreach (linha in linhasArquivo)
{
    var linhaDatabase = colecaoMortos[linha.NrCpf];
}
```

Não sei se é suficiente, mas agora você já teria código pra comparar as duas coleções na sua *View*. Se precisar eu estendo a resposta.

Comment: Olá, esta é uma forma interessante, que eu desconhecia. Fiquei apenas com uma dúvida até o momento. No helper você referenciou a variável **fileContents** que tenho em meu controller. Porém ao criar o Helper e utilizar a mesma, recebo erro. Poreria explicar um pouco melhor esta parte?

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Foi erro meu mesmo. `fileContents` e `arquivoBruto` é a mesma coisa. Na refatoração acabei não prestando atenção neste detalhe. Veja se com a edição ficou mais claro.

Comment: Ao popular a coleção (linhasArquivos) eu recebo um erro falando que esperava um **IEnumerable**: *Argument type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Models.LinhamortoArquivo>' is not assignable to parameter type 'ModelsLinhaMortoArquivo'*

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Não consigo entender onde está o erro. Acho que é o caso de abrir uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Vou verificar se aparece outras respostas, pois pode ser que seja apresentada outra forma. Caso não ocorra, sigo seu conselho e foco em sua resposta.