# O que é Hashcode e qual sua finalidade?

Tags: programação-funcional, convenções-de-nome, hashcode

Tenho observado que a utilização de `hashcode` é utilizada em comparações, mas o que significa o termo? Sua utilização em programação é específica em comparação?

Comment: Em específico para programação funcional eu não sei, mas existe uma possível duplicata sobre esse assunto (em Java): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11108/qual-a-import%C3%A2ncia-de-implementar-o-m%C3%A9todo-hashcode-em-java

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O termo *hash* "costuma" ser traduzido por espalhamento. Algumas pessoas podem dizer que é triturar (o dado até ficar um pedacinho).

## Usos

#### Tabela *hash*

A principal finalidade é usar em chaves de tabelas de *hash* que precisam organizar os dados de uma forma numérica simples.

Uma tabela *hash* consegue localizar um elemento quase sempre em complexidade O(1), ou seja, não importa o tamanho da tabela ele acha sempre no mesmo tempo. Isso é o mesmo que acontece com um *array*.

Como ele consegue colocar dados diversos que não são números, ou pelo menos não são números simples e em sequencia e permanecer tão rápido?

Ele pega o dado real aplicando uma fórmula para descobrir qual é o número que aquele dado corresponde. Esse cálculo é feito no que chamamos *hash function*. Uma boa função tenta evitar que dois dados diferentes gerem o mesmo resultado. Embora seja provável que não gere repetidos, acontece, especialmente em volumes grandes de dados. Quando isso ocorre, a complexidade vai para O(m), onde `m` é a quantidade de repetições. Como não costuma ter muita repetição, dizemos que a complexidade de uma tabela *hash* é quase O(1). Só não é 1 quando tem repetição. Em tese em um caso extremo o O(1) poderia virar O(n), ou seja, ter que analisar tudo. Na prática isso não ocorre, a não ser que faça esta piada:

```
function getHashCode() { return 42; }
```

Aí todas chaves gerarão o mesmo resultado e só terá repetição na tabela.

O *hash code* pode ser só calculado na hora que precisa, ou pode ser armazenado no objeto trocando tempo de processamento por espaço ocupado.

Se um objeto não pode ter uma forma de calcular seu *hash* de forma confiável, ele não pode ser usado em uma tabela de *hash*. Claro que todo objeto pode ser *hasheável*, mas se isso será bem organizado ou não, depende da linguagem e do programador.

Linguagens como Java e C# obrigam todo objeto ter uma função que calcula o *hash*. Se vai armazenar ou não (cache) é problema de cada objeto. Algumas pessoas dizem que isso é um erro e que deveria ter uma interface `Hashable` para usar em objetos que podem fazer bom uso do código. Outros dizem que já que praticamente todo objeto pode ser usado como chave, então é melhor obrigar em todos.

Um objeto pode usar a implementação padrão ou fazer um próprio. Muitas vezes tem que fazer o próprio usando as partes do objeto que são relevantes para **identificar** o objeto.

A comparação não é tão boa, mas vamos dizer que é o RG do objeto (no Brasil, o documento de identidade da pessoa), que inclusive pode ter repetido porque os estados é que controlam isso. É verdade que a identidade completa do objeto RG seria seu número e órgão emissor, aí ficaria único.

#### `switch`

Algumas linguagens usam isso para poder usar estruturas mais complexas em `case` do `switch`.

O `case` precisa ser rápido, não pode fazer comparações complexas, precisa ter um padrão fácil de localização. Ele se assemelha muito com uma tabela *hash*. Usando o *hash code* da *string* dá para tornar o `switch` mais poderoso e aceitar um tipo que é muito útil em uma seleção múltipla.

#### Integridade

Em alguns casos o código pode ser gravado ou transmitido junto servindo de verificação da integridade do dado. Depois ele calcula de novo e vê se bate com o que foi transmitido pra ver se houve alguma corrupção. Não é uma forma muito confiável, mas pode ser usada se souber o que está fazendo e puder lidar com algum possível erro.

#### Comparações

Outros usos podem ser feitos talvez para otimizar algum algoritmo. O código *hash* pode servir para identificar que algo é diferente mais rapidamente do que olhar um objeto enorme. Ele junto de um trecho do objeto pode **quase** garantir a unicidade. Ele sozinho não é tão útil para isto. Não que isto costume ser usado na prática.

De maneira geral é usado para comparações, mas nada impede de ser usado para outras coisas. Dá pra ser criativo.

## Outros tipos

Não confundir com outros tipos de *hash code*, normalmente enormes que são usados para assinar ou autenticar objetos. Esse é bem pequeno, geralmente 4 bytes.

## Extra

Não vejo porque seria diferente em programação funcional, a não ser que pode haver otimizações do *pattern matching* como o citado sobre o `switch`.

O que eu posso dizer é que em programação funcional os objetos tendem a ser mais propícios para uso em tabela *hash* já que eles são imutáveis. Essa é uma característica importante do objeto para usar em tabela de espalhamento.

## Exemplo de implementação

```
public override int GetHashCode() {
    unchecked {
        int hash = 17;
        hash *= 23 + field1.GetHashCode(); //cada um tem sua própria fórmula
        hash *= 23 + field2.GetHashCode();
        hash *= 23 + field3.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/HashCode.cs).

Um `int` pode ter seu código como o próprio objeto. De fato é [assim que é feito](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/2d2b91f1bdc71dbb.html) ([no .NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Int32.cs,75)).

Algumas pessoas preferem o fato 31 outras preferem 16777619 e base 2166136261.

[Documentação do C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Object_GetHashCode).

Comment: Por que é feita esta multiplicação? Por que não podemos apenas retornar a soma dos gethashcode dos campos?

Comment: @DanOver acho que está melhor explicado em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/353963/101. Preciso ver se escrevo uma resposta melhor em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356435/101.