# Um dicionário Python é tão eficiente quanto uma árvore ou um hash?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dicionário, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Eu uso muito dicionários em Python:

```
dic = dict() #ou
dic = {}

dic['113654'] = {'nome': 'João', 'idade': 21}
dic['853872'] = {'nome': 'Maria', 'idade': 27}
dic['427845'] = {'nome': 'Fernando', 'idade': 33}
dic['720720'] = {'nome': 'Lucas', 'idade': 16}
```

Eles facilitam muito verificar se uma chave existe e pegar seu valor:

```
cod = '853872'
if cod in dic:
    return dic[cod]
```

Minha pergunta é: usar dicionários dessa forma é eficiente? Dicionários em Python implementam uma maneira eficiente de encontrar as chaves (*hash*, árvore, etc.)? Ou quando meu dicionário ficar muito grande convém usar uma estrutura de dados mais tradicionalmente eficiente como uma árvore ou um *hash* por exemplo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A implementação interna do dicionário de Python é usando tabelas *hash*, então tem complexidade O(1) para achar chaves, isto pode ser confirmado na [wiki oficial de Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) (obrigado ao AlexCiuffa).

Ele é, em tese, e em quase todas as situações, mais rápida que uma árvore que tem complexidade O(log n), mas ele não pode ter as chaves naturalmente classificadas como uma árvore pode, e não pode ter chaves repetidas. Um dicionário era [não "ordenado"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/101). Segundo o jsbueno abaixo em comentário agora ele consegue ser ordenado usando uma estrutura auxiliar, então mantém o O(1) para acesso ao elemento e consegue atravessar todos elementos na ordem que foram inseridos, ao custo de ocupar mais espaço que poderia, o que para Python não é um grande problema porque já fazia isto antes. Ele ainda é não classificado e só poderia ser assim de forma eficiente com uma árvore ou algo parecido.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Fontes que suportam essa resposta (e uma referência para quem quiser aprofundar neste assunto) são: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity (complexidade da busca em dicionário e outras estruturas) e https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys (mostra como o dicionário funciona e como utiliza `hash`).

Comment: Se ele é basicamente um hash já resolve meu problema. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @AlexCiuffa links excelentes!

Comment: Sobre não ser ordenado - o código dos dicionários de Python foi refatorado na versão 3.6, e a partir da 3.7 foi oficializado que os dicionários respeitam a ordem de inserção de chaves - (como o collections.OrderedDict, que agora vai para o museu)

Comment: @jsbueno então isso quer dizer que ele não é mais um *hash* e sim uma árvore ou algo parecido, e portanto não tem mais como ser O(1), pode ser O(logN) ou O(N), o que seria terrível e duvido que seja, ou ainda para ser O(1) teria duas estruturas, uma para garantir a ordem e outra para dar a O(1), o que ocuparia muito espaço.

Comment: é um hash, mas as estruturas auxíliares, paralelas aos registros de hash, permitem que a ordem de inserção seja recuperada. Eu não vi o código em C como ficou, mas deve ser bem interessante dar uma olhada. A inserção e lookup continuam sendo O(1). Tem alguma lógica extra na remoção de chaves - aí não sei se mudou o tempo O.

Comment: @jsbueno Então está confirmando que há uma estrutura extra para manter a ordem e ocupa bem mais espaço? Tem referências sobre tudo isto?

Comment: O"muito espaço" na segunda estrutura pode ser tão compacto quanto uma link para o próximo hash em cada entrada - 8 bytes por registro a mais - não fica tanto assim, comparado com o tamano típico de um objeto Python que vai estar no "value"  (da ordme de dezenas de bytes de qualquer forma).

Comment: Realmente está bem difícl achar  a referência - o interessante é que mesmo com esses dados a mais, como foi numa refatoração completa que criou um novo layout em memoria para os dados , mesmo assim os novos dicionários são 20% menores que os antigos, em média - acho que a issue que apresenta o novo código centraliza as discussões: https://bugs.python.org/issue27350  aqui é a fonte em "alto nível" https://morepypy.blogspot.com/2015/01/faster-more-memory-efficient-and-more.html

Comment: é, Python já tem um desperdício de espaço grande naturalmente então não fará tanta diferença e se já havia desperdício por outro motivo que agora resolveram pode ficar comparativamente interessante, embora não seja o mais eficiente possível se desconsiderar a comparação específica. Deve ser o que em C# é o `KeydCollection` https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56001/101.